# Ansible cannot run the BASH on remote host

Tags: bash, ssh, ansible

I have 3 servers in my LAB: Ansible Server, Test Server, and MySQL

I have a bash script in my Test Server to run ssh port forwarding for the remote Mysql. Here is my bash in my Test Server:

```
cat /tmp/mysql_ssh.sh

#!/bin/bash
    
ssh -L *:12345:localhost:3306 -fN -o"ProxyJump myjumphost"    \
        -i ~/.ssh/my.pem mysql_user@mysql_ip
```

This bash works locally, I can  login to the remote MySQL server by `0.0.0.0:12345`

I would like to execute my bash from Ansible Server, but both of 2 playbooks don't work:

```
- name: Test Server SSH port forwarding
  hosts: Test-Server
  remote_user: ansible

  task:
  - name: SSH port forwarding
    ansible.builtin.shell: /tmp/mysql_ssh.sh
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
```

or

```
- name: Test Server SSH port forwarding
  hosts: Test-Server
  remote_user: ansible

  task:     
  - name: SSH port forwarding
    ansible.builtin.command: 
      cmd: ssh -L *:12345:localhost:3306 -fN -o"ProxyJump myjumphost" -i ~/.ssh/my.pem mysql_user@mysql_ip
```

These playbooks don't have any error messages. The playbook will still be executed but seems like nothing happened. I cannot find `0.0.0.0:12345` from `netstat`

I am very new to Ansible, any help is appreciated!

Comment: try adding `</dev/null` at the end of your `ssh` tunnel command

Comment: @P.... Thanks for the reply. I tried the add </dev/null at the end but the playbook still doesn't work

Comment: I think you are trying to shoot ansible to create a tunnel and end. However, when ansible is dying, it is killing your command(ssh), try removing `-f` and keep `-N`

Comment: @P.... You are right! My Test server is listening port 12345 after I ran the playbook! But Ansible playbook hangs. I am guessing it may be stuck in some command prompt. But at least I know what's the root cause. I will keep troubleshooting and studying Ansible. Seems like I have some misunderstanding with how Ansible executes the command/BASH on the remote host. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try [script module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html)

```
- name: Run a script using an executable
  ansible.builtin.script: /tmp/mysql_ssh.sh
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```